# Java. how many times appears every symbol in matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is 2-dimensional array 10x10, filled with random english letters(both uppercase and lowercase) How to count, how many times appears every symbol in array?

Comment: You can map use of HashMap for the same

Comment: Please, share, what you've done so far. The basic idea is it doesn't matter how many dimensions your array has, you just need to iterate through each item and count it

Comment: @Tatjana I mentioned answer for the same . Please let me know if you need help in understanding that

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 stream :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CountCharacter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Character[][] array = new Character[][] {
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
            {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','a'},
        };



        Map<Character, Long> data =Stream.of(array)
        .flatMap(Stream::of)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

Here I have converted a array to stream , then flatten the 2D array and then converted to HashMap with keys as character and value as count ->>`Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())` .

Without using Java Stream:

```
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hashMap =new HashMap<>();
    for (Character[] oneD: array) {
        for (Character elem: oneD) {
            hashMap.put(elem, hashMap.getOrDefault(elem, 0)+1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are new on stackoverflow but please take care next time before asking for help you should always show what you have tried so far .

Please check this solution . It will help you count the frequency

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm  = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(hm.containsKey(arr[i][j])){
                int freq = hm.get(arr[i][j]);
                hm.put(arr[i][j],++freq);
            } else {
                hm.put(arr[i][j],1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am creating the HashMap of integer,integer . In your case you can create the HashMap of Character,Integer.